# Drawing MRI sequence

Tags: diagrams

Does anyone know of existing LaTeX macros or packages for drawing Magnetic Resonance Imaging pulse
sequences? I didn't find anything online.
This is an example of pulse sequence:

[pulse sequence http://lapmal.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/lapmal/files/shared/proj/ed_mri/pulse_sequence.jpg](http://lapmal.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/lapmal/files/shared/proj/ed_mri/pulse_sequence.jpg)

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: [Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  It would be helpful if you described what MRI pulse sequences are, and perhaps provided an example of what it usually looks like.

Comment: @JP-Ellis  MRI pulse sequence are diagrams used in magnetic resonance imaging. I didn't explained it because I think that who knows how to draw them also knows what they are. I'm sorry for not having described it well. I edited the question adding an image as example.

Comment: Such diagrams are definitely possible in LaTeX.  If you have the data already in a file of the plots, then you can produce these using [`PGFPlots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots).  You could also use [`TikZ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) do draw them manually.  Also, since the plots are fairly simple, it wouldn't be too hard to create a few macros and/or styles to automate a few steps at once.  Have a go at using these packages, and if you encounter further issues feel free to ask again here.  Unfortunately, some people here don't really like "draw this for me" questions.

Comment: @JP-Ellis I didn't want anyone to draw it for me, sorry for giving that feeling. I only needed some suggestions because it's my first time with diagrams in LaTeX and I was wondering if any specific package for MRI exists. I will try TikZ. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think your question is perfectly reasonable, and indeed you're not asking a "draw it for me" question.  I just saw that you unfortunately got down-voted so I just wanted to let you know why some people might be doing that.

Comment: [Did you have a look at this blog](https://tinkertailorsoldiersponge.wordpress.com/category/tinker/latex/)? It explains a method to generate Pulse Sequence Diagrams using metapost (but most of its links are dead…).

Comment: @Clément It seems to be very useful! Thank you!

Comment: May I give you three advices? a) If you found the solution in that blog, adding your own answer that reflects the technique you use would benefit to the whole community. b) If you don't understand what this blog is doing, edit your question by explaining why you're stuck. c) If the material in the blog is not what you need, edit your question to reflect that you know about this solution, but that it doesn't fit your need for this and that reason.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use it and then I will update the question!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution to draw MR pulse sequences and came across the following website:

http://nmrwiki.org/wiki/index.php?title=Pulse_sequence_drawing

Unfortunately, it seems like the project died out.

I then came across this question and saw the suggestion in the comments linking to a [blog](https://tinkertailorsoldiersponge.wordpress.com/category/tinker/latex/) using MetaPost to draw sequences. For those who are interested, I've dug up the dead links on the Internet Archive, fixed some font issues, and put the code up on [Github](https://github.com/dangom/mr-sequence-diagrams) (with proper credits to the original author, of course), so that others can profit from it as well. I've used it successfully and found it to be a useful and quick for drawing publication quality sequences.

Here's an example EPI sequence:
[image: EPI with blipped-CAIPI]